# ExtJS convering an Ext.app.Controller to an Ext.app.Application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am trying to convert a class that extends `Ext.app.Controller` to extending `Ext.app.Application`. Since `Ext.app.Application` is a child class of `Ext.app.Controller` I assumed that simply changing the class being extended would work, instead however, it causes an error in the console that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined`. The error occurs at the `this.callParent(arguments)` inside the `constructor: function`, Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Your description is not enough. Where is it failing (file/line class/method). Can you provide some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @lontivero I added where it occurs, its a very large class, I am not sure my employer would appreciate me posting it all. I am hoping that perhaps someone experienced something similar.

Comment: I think with that description is almost impossible help you. Where are you calling the this.callParent methods? Give us some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a constructor within a Ext.app.Application class changes will come with 4.2 but till that use the launch method for example to apply stuff. And do NOT extend.

Application is sort of a singleton instance an get just intialized by calling

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: {
                html: 'My App'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Trying to run more instances result in problems but you will be able to do this with 4.2 like so

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'MyApp'
...
});

Ext.application('MyApp.Application');
```